# Why does my if else stament work but when I replace it with a function it doesn't?

Tags: php, function, echo

I am creating dynamically some accordions (the number depends on the database output) which contain input forms and want to keep them open if an error is reported after input validation. When I use an if else statement within my echo that creates the forms it works as expected. But if I replace the if else with a function the page doesn't even load correctly.

The following code (striped down to a minimal example) adds "w3-show" or nothing to the div class and works fine. The `$player_edit_err[$id]` will contain the error message as its value or will be an empty array if no error is reported. I am initializing this array after $_POST has been submitted like this: `$player_edit_err = array();` and after validation like this: `if (empty($new_player_name)) {$player_edit_err[$id] = "Please enter a Name.";}` the array will be empty or contain the error as a string. At the end I am showing the complete $_POST code.

```
foreach ($players_in_tourn as $id => $name) {
  echo "<div class='w3-hide";

  if (!empty($player_edit_err[$id])) {
    echo " w3-show";
  } else {
    echo "";
  }

  echo "'><form action='" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "' method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='new_player_name' value='$name'>
            <input type='hidden' name='player_id' value='$id'>
            <span>" . $player_edit_err[$id] . "</span>
          </form>
        </div>";
}
```

But if I want to place the if else statement inside a function in order to tide-up the code like this:

```
function accordionShow($error) {
  if (!empty($error)) {
    return " w3-show";
} else {
    return "";}
}
```

and try to call the function by replacing the if else statement like this: `echo accordionShow($player_edit_err[$id]);` or `accordionShow($player_edit_err[$id]);` it does not work. Please note that I have tested this with using either echo or return in the function. In fact, when I try to call the function the list of accordions is not created completely. It stops after the first one with the rest of the page also not loading. I don't know if this is relevant, but I am also getting an `Uninitialized string offset:` error message in the php log file. The php error is referring to the  `$player_edit_err[$id]` string when the code runs fine (i.e. when not using the function).

Any help to understand this problem greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the complete $_POST code

```
// Processing form data when form is submitted
foreach ($players_in_tourn as $id => $name) {
    if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && isset($_POST["edit_player$id"])) {
        $message = "POST for edit_player";

        //Define variables
        $player_id = $_POST["player_id"];
        $player_name = $_POST["player_name"];
        $new_player_name = $_POST["new_player_name"];
        $player_edit_err = array();

        // Make the function for form data input validation available 
        require('functions/functions.php');

        // Validate tourn_name
        if (empty($new_player_name)) {
            $player_edit_err[$id] = "Please enter a Name.";
        } else {
            $new_player_name = test_input($new_player_name);
        }

        // // Validate player ... check if it exists already in the tournament
        $new_array = $_SESSION['playersInTourn'];
        unset($new_array[$player_id]);

        if (in_array($new_player_name, $new_array)) {
            $player_edit_err[$id] = "Player $new_player_name already exists.";
        }

        $_SESSION['errors'] = $player_edit_err;

        // Then insert the tournament player
        if ($player_edit_err[$id] == "") {
            // If no errors insert the tournament player
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE Players SET name =? WHERE idPlayers=?");
            $stmt->execute([$new_player_name, $player_id]);

            // Redirect to Tournament page
            header("location: add_players.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want a single div to have both `w3-hide` and `w3-show` classes?  We cannot see you `$player_edit_err` array data, so we don't know why your first `$id` is not a found key in your array.  What is `$player_edit_err`?  Is it an array or a string?  Is it declared somewhere?  I wouldn't be creating a new custom function for this anyhow... `echo !empty($player_edit_err[$id]) ? ' w3-show' : '';`

Comment: `echo '<div class="w3-hide' . (!empty($player_edit_err[$id]) ? ' w3-show' : '') . '">';`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip. I edited my post to include more info about how am I constructing the `$player_edit_err array`. Your suggestion works nicely, although I still don't understand why it is not working when replaced by a function call. Should I mark this as solved?

Comment: To answer you other question ... why am I adding w3-show in the same div with w3-hide? Because that's the only way I managed to keep the accordion open when my span contains an error message. I am a complete noob with javascript and every method I found and tried on the web didn't work. I understand that the accordion closes after POST because the page re-loads after interacting with the database and its initial state is to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

When `if (empty($new_player_name)) {` and `if (in_array($new_player_name, $new_array)) {` are not satisfied/`true`, then `if ($player_edit_err[$id] == "") {` will generate an error because the `$id` key of the `$player_edit_err` array does not exist.

If I am an honest, I would rewrite this whole flow (in fact, I'd redesign your form that points to this script so that array type fields are named `edit_player[$id]` instead of `edit_player$id`).

However, to quickly patch your script, just use an `empty()` check.

```
if (empty($player_edit_err[$id])) {
```

I will make one important note: prepared statements are designed to be declared once (before entering a loop) then executed as many times as needed inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

you have to call the function if you want it to execute. with your code, you have just fefined it. you have to call it like this: `accordionShow()`

so your code will be like:

```
function accordionShow($error) {
  if (!empty($error)) {
    return " w3-show";
} else {
    return "";}
}

accordionShow($error)
```

dont forget to pass $error as a parameter to the function

Comment: But I did mention in my post that I already tried to call the function with various ways. For example I tried `accordionShow($player_edit_err[$id]);` or to make sure that there isn't any problem with the `$player_edit_err[$id]` which I am getting from the array I tried calling it with some manually entered string like this: `accordionShow("My error message here");`